# How do I enable day/night cycle in old Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to figure this out for days now. A world of mine that I made a very long time ago in MCPE (back when glass, bricks and shears were unlimited and worlds were limited to 256  blocks in size--can't remember which version I created the world in) somehow got frozen in time. I'm trying to fix that *without* enabling cheats so that I can still earn achievements in the world. I tried NBTedit and NBTExplorer on the level.dat file, but both have failed. Nothing else I've tried has worked either. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you have to use cheats on it to fix the time cycle.

Fix anything that could've went wrong in the world. Here are some commands to help you:

```
/gamerule dodaylightcycle true
/alwaysday false
```

Comment: A note. If your world was created with cheats disabled, open your game to LAN and enable cheats from the in-game menu. A quick and easy way of going about this.

Comment: @GipsyD you shouldn't need LAN on to enable cheats